# Insert bulk records from sql server to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, bulkinsert, sql-insert

I would like to sync mssql and mysql using php script so that when ever I press sync button by selecting tables then php script have to fetch records from mssql and insert that record into mysql ,That works fine with few thousands of records,but If I try to insert 100000 records into mysql.I got error like "mysql server gone away" and "500 Internal server error"

- Is There any way to Insert large amount of records to MYSQL using
  PHP?  or any other suggestions please?
- There are some questions
  related to this in stackoverflow but I can't find any working
  solution

my code is

```
<?php
include("db.php");
//get relevant records
$ms_sql_query= "select * from Schedule";
$ms_result = mssql_query($ms_sql_query);
$ms_numRows = mssql_num_rows($ms_result);
$insertCount=0;
$updateCount=0;
if($ms_numRows > 0)
{
    while($row = mssql_fetch_array($ms_result))
    {
        $ret=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM feesh WHERE SyncID=".$row['SyncID']);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($ret);

        if($count==0) 
        {
            $sync_query="insert into feesh (Schid, installNo, Studentid, DueDate, Specialfee, TransportFee, Tution, Others, Tu_Status, TR_Status, oth_status, ADMIN_NO,SyncID) VALUES ('".$row['Schid']."','".$row['installNo']."','".$row['Studentid']."','".$row['DueDate']."','".$row['Specialfee']."','".$row['TransportFee']."','".$row['Tution']."','".$row['Others']."','".$row['Tu_Status']."','".$row['TR_Status']."','".$row['oth_status']."','".$row['ADMIN_NO']."','".$row['SyncID']."')";
            $insertCount++;
        }
        else 
        {
            $sync_query="update feesh set Schid = '".$row['Schid']."', installNo = '".$row['installNo']."', Studentid = '".$row['Studentid']."', DueDate= '".$row['DueDate']."', Specialfee = '".$row['Specialfee']."', TransportFee = '".$row['TransportFee']."', Tution='".$row['Tution']."', Others='".$row['Others']."', Tu_Status='".$row['Tu_Status']."', TR_Status='".$row['TR_Status']."', oth_status='".$row['oth_status']."', ADMIN_NO = '".$row['ADMIN_NO']."' where SyncID = '".$row['SyncID']."'";
            $updateCount++;
        }
        mysql_query($sync_query)or die("err".mysql_error());
    }
}

?>
```

(Note:I also tried to create one giant sql insert query and process but that also give same error)

Comment: MySQL is certainly killing you for high resource usage. See my.cnf to increase performance and ask your DB admin if there is one.

Comment: Look into 'batch' inserts using transactions to do 100's of rows at a time. Some links tha\t may be useful: [/bulk-insert-into-a-mysql-database](http://jeffrick.com/2010/03/23/bulk-insert-into-a-mysql-database/), also:  [improve-mysql-insert-performance](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/03/31/improve-mysql-insert-performance/)